# Bulk insert with SQLite.swift, performant way?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite.swift

I'm trying to do a bulk insert with SQLite Swift. However, I'm not 100% sure if my code is correct.

The Swift code I've settled on (because it delivered the best performance timewise) is:

```
do {
   try DB.transaction { () -> Void in
     for index in 0...num_docs {
       table.insert(data <- "test", data_num <- index)
      } 
    } 
} catch _ {
 throw DataAccessError.Transaction_Error
}
```

EDIT ----

If I would use the following code in swift, inserting 10000 docs drops from +/- 12 secs to 0.8 secs. What sounds too good to be true.

```
  let docsTrans = DB.prepare("INSERT INTO TEST_DB (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)")
    do {
       try DB.transaction(.Deferred) { () -> Void in
         for index in 0...num_docs {
           try docsTrans.run("test", index)
          } 
        }
     } catch _ {
            throw DataAccessError.Insert_Error
        }
```

Comment: It confirms my own performance tests: https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/wiki/Performance

Comment: Looking at the code, this (unfortunately) makes a lot of sense. The table.insert function will generate a 10000 sql statements which are then processed by SQLite one at a time. By contrast, doing the `prepare` first is one call, and `run` calls `sqlite3_step` which just passes through the data to be inserted.  Short of providing a bulk insert method, or trying to do statement prep &  caching in SQLite Swift, it's hard to imagine how to do this faster with the `table.insert` design. Nice job coming up with the alternative!

Comment: @Swennemen thank you for the question and the solution! Can you please share the definition of the DB varibale?

Comment: Thanks for this find swennemen! It took 45 seconds for me to insert 6000 items into my db and this raw form only takes 1.8 seconds. That's 26 times faster!

Comment: this means last one option is good right?